# Fill in NA value based on similar key identifier in R

Tags: r

I am doing the SpaceTitanic in the Kaggle competition.  I would like to fill in the missing value NA if they belong to the same group.  So far example:

```
    PassengerId = c('0001_01', '0003_01', '0003_02'),
    HomePlanet = c('Europa', 'Mars', NA)
```

I would like to fill the last PassengerID HomePlanet as Mars since they belong to the same group (the first 4 characters in the PassengerId column.

What's the best way of doing the above in R?  I can do this by creating 3 different objects and using the join method but I think there must be a better way.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this in a data frame or actually two separate character vectors?

Comment: It is a data frame.  I am going to accept an answer from @margusl. It is very succinct and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are leaning towards Tidyverse, filling missing values can be handled through `tidyr::fill()`. To make sure it doesn't fill over group boundaries, the dataset should be grouped first; we can group directly by `str_split_i(PassengerId, "_", 1)`, the first part of `PassengerId`. Though note that there must exist at least one `HomePlanet` value per group; and if existing `HomePlanet` values per group are not constant, no existing values are updated and `NA`-s are just filled according to the chosen `.direction`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df <- tibble( PassengerId = c('0001_01', '0003_01', '0003_02'),
              HomePlanet = c('Europa', 'Mars', NA)) 
df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   PassengerId HomePlanet
#>   <chr>       <chr>     
#> 1 0001_01     Europa    
#> 2 0003_01     Mars      
#> 3 0003_02     <NA>
df |>
  group_by(grp = str_split_i(PassengerId, "_", 1)) |>
  fill(HomePlanet, .direction = "downup") |>
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   PassengerId HomePlanet grp  
#>   <chr>       <chr>      <chr>
#> 1 0001_01     Europa     0001 
#> 2 0003_01     Mars       0003 
#> 3 0003_02     Mars       0003
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your described solution of creating a reference table for `PlanetID`s and `HomePlanet`s is a good solution. It'll work for any ID/name combinations and scales nicely too.

Here is one way to do it:

```r
PassengerId = c('0001_01', '0003_01', '0003_02')
HomePlanet = c('Europa', 'Mars', NA)

library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble(PassengerId,
         HomePlanet) |>
  separate(PassengerId,
           c("PlanetID", "PassengerPlanetID"),
           remove = FALSE)

ref <-
  df |>
  distinct(PlanetID, HomePlanet) |>
  drop_na()

df |>
  select(-HomePlanet) |>
  left_join(ref, relationship = "many-to-many")
#> Joining with `by = join_by(PlanetID)`
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   PassengerId PlanetID PassengerPlanetID HomePlanet
#>   <chr>       <chr>    <chr>             <chr>     
#> 1 0001_01     0001     01                Europa    
#> 2 0003_01     0003     01                Mars      
#> 3 0003_02     0003     02                Mars
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R we could `na.omit` by group, which we identify by 1st to 4th `substr`ing, using `ave`.

```
> transform(df, HomePlanet=ave(HomePlanet, substr(PassengerId, 1, 4), FUN=na.omit))
  PassengerId HomePlanet
1     0001_01     Europa
2     0003_01       Mars
3     0003_02       Mars
```

This assumes at least one non-NA in the groups.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(PassengerId = c("0001_01", "0003_01", "0003_02"
), HomePlanet = c("Europa", "Mars", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```